# Directly accessing angular2 routes from browser breaks

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Before angular2, if we want to get to a route in angularJS directly from the browser, lets say a `signup` route we use the hashbang approach (`#/`) like this - `www.example.com/#/signup`

But with angular2 this dosent work.
I can only access the signup route directly clicking the signup button on the index route - `www.example.com/`

I have `<base href="/">` added already.

Please would like to know how i can access the signup route directly from the browser url bar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. You must to define your location strategy in app.

```
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from "angular2/router";
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
 ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
 ...
 bind(LocationStrategy).toClass(HashLocationStrategy)
]);
```

So, if you want to use urls with #, your strategy is HashLocationStrategy

Comment: Okay Thanks. But now I want to have my cake and still  eat it. Can it be possible to beautify the url by removing the hashbag and still hit the route like `www.example.com/signup` instead of `www.example.com/#/signup`

Comment: Yes, that is PathLocationStrategy, there are plenty stuff on Overflow about that.